# clustering based on tags in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, grouping, cluster-analysis

I have search system where books are tagged, every book is marked with some tags.
Ex.

```
book: tags
book1: u'NIPU', u'YPAM', u'AXEI', u'WJQT', u'SNUR', u'FJQV', u'UTMQ'
book2: u'NKEM', u'JAQQ', u'EFOY', u'DAGS', u'FJQV'
book3: u'YPAM', u'AXEI', u'WJQT', u'SNUR', u'FJQV', u'UTMQ', u'UJHA'
....
..
.
```

here I have thousands of books with different tags. I was looking for some clustering mechanism where I can create list based on tags.
Example:

```
tag: No of books

NIPU: 12390
FJQV: 2345
..
.
NIPU,FJQV: 1243
SNUR,UJHA: 2343
..
.
NIPU,FJQV,SNUR: 1290
..
.
EFOY,WJQT,FJQV,UTMQ: 1894
....
...
..
.
YPAM,AXEI,WJQT,SNUR,FJQV,UTMQ,UJHA: 1
```

any pointer will be really helpful, I spent some time on kmeans but was not sure how to use it in this scenario.

Comment: Hi ! never worked with numpy before but what have you tried till now. I can suggest making a dict and perform a normal binary search but that will also be inefficient

Comment: what format are these data in?  what code have you written so far?  i don't see how `kmeans` could make sense for this -- can you provide your reasoning?

Comment: This looks like a classical case of unsupervised learning (look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning). There are many approaches to it. Pick one, try it out, and post a more precise and programming-oriented question. SO is not the place to ask for pointers, check http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

I don't think kmeans is appropriate in this situation, since you're looking for equalities in the data, not similarities. It looks like what you want to find are frequent itemsets. This can be a computationally demanding task depending on the size of your data, but there are tricks to cleverly interrogate the search space.

Look into the a priori principle, and specifically the Fk-1 X Fk-1 method of candidate pruning. Chapter 6 of this book will guide you: http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/index.php

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for

### frequent itemset mining

(i.e. frequent tags, and frequent tag combinations)

not for cluster analysis. k-means will get you nowhere - wrong tool solving the wrong problem.